# elasticsearch: find the newest elements, return "asc"

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch in Go, I need to search for the newest last X elements, ordered by time.

I think having something like this will accomplish the goal:

```
"query": {"constant_score": {}},
"sort": {"time": {"order": "desc"}},
"size": X
```

However, this would return the newest elements in reverse order, wouldn't it?

Is there a way to return the newest X elements in ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

This request will give you the oldest elements matching the query.

To achieve your goal, you could make a count query (ordering not needed) and then a desc sorted request with the start parameter set to count-X. This solution is ugly and very inefficient.

You'd be a lot better off desc sorting the results in your Go app.